# Building Insertion Sort. Not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: ruby, arrays, sorting

The goal is to see how insertion sort finds and inserts a number into a pre-sorted array. I'm supposed to pop the last number from the array and insert it into its correct chronological place in the array.

The code seems to work for the first example, but not the second. In the second example the correct answer seems to come in the fourth iteration even though there are integers in the array.

It feels like I need to `break` or `return` and stop looping somewhere, but I'm not sure where.

```
def  insertionSort( ar) 
  count = ar.count
  value = ar.pop

  p ar << value if value >= ar.last

  reversed = ar.reverse

  ar.count.times do |index|
    reversed.unshift(reversed.first) if reversed.count < count

    if reversed[index + 1] > value
      reversed[index] = reversed[index+1]
    else
      reversed[index] = value
    end

    puts reversed.reverse.join(' ')
  end
end

ar = [2, 4, 6, 8, 3] 
insertionSort( ar )
#=> 2 4 6 8 8
#=> 2 4 6 6 8
#=> 2 4 4 6 8
#=> 2 3 4 6 8

negatives = [-3, -6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
insertionSort( negatives )
#=> -3 -6 7 8 9 9
#=> -3 -6 7 8 8 9
#=> -3 -6 7 7 8 9
#=> -3 -6 5 7 8 9
#=> -3 5 5 7 8 9
```

Comment: "....its correct chronological place..." I know what you mean, but chronological is not the correct term here :)

Comment: The first line is supsicious: #=> 2 4 6 8 8 i.e. you have the 8 twice, I would start there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.  I needed a break and a puts on the else statement.

```
def  insertionSort( ar) 
  count = ar.count
  value = ar.pop

  p ar << value if value >= ar.last
  reversed = ar.reverse

  ar.count.times do |index|
    reversed.unshift(reversed.first) if reversed.count < count

    if reversed[index + 1] > value
      reversed[index] = reversed[index+1]
      puts reversed.reverse.join(' ')
    elsif reversed[index + 1] == value
      reversed.slice!(index)
      puts reversed.reverse.join(' ')
      break
    else
      reversed[index] = value
      puts reversed.reverse.join(' ')
      break
    end
  end
end

ar = [2, 4, 6, 8, 3] 
insertionSort( ar )

negatives = [-3, -6, 7, 8, 9, 5]
insertionSort( negatives )
```